# Angular; Changing component on form input

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am new to angular. I am creating a search engine project that has the component switch on input in an input box and the input transferred to an input box in the component that is being changed to. How would I go about doing this?
The components that I would like to switch between are as follows on the app component:

```
<app-search-page></app-search-page>
<app-search-results-page></app-search-results-page>
```

Within app search page is the initial input box:

```
<input class = "search" (input)="changeComponent($event)">
```

(The "changeComponent($event)" wasn't working)

In the app search results page is the second input box, the one to receive the contents of the initial:

```
<input class = "input">
```

Comment: did try anything can you paste the code here

Comment: @Robert I have done so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Service to let the both of them exchange information. Here is an example:

this is your service. It stores and provides a string value named searchItem. Attention! You have to import and provide this Service in you app.module.ts!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

    private searchItem: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

    constructor() { }

    getSearchItem(): Observable<string> {
        return this.searchItem.asObservable();
    }

    getSearchItemValue(): string {
        return this.searchItem.getValue();
    }

    setSearchItem(val: string) {
        this.searchItem.next(val);
    }
}
```

Your AppSearchResultPageComponent subscribes to this service and gets updated whenever the value inside the service changes.

```
import {StorageService} from 'storage.service.ts';

private searchItem: string = '';

constructor(
   private storageService: StorageService
){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Update with every change
    this.storageService.getSearchTerm().subscribe(term => {
        this. searchItem = term; 
    });
}
```

And your AppSearchPageComponent has to set the value to the StorageSevice after each keypress:

```
import {StorageService} from 'storage.service.ts';

private searchItem: string = '';

constructor(
 private storageService: StorageService
){}

// store the current value of searchItem to the service
private changeComponent(event): void {
    this.storageService.setSearchItem(searchItem);
}
```

Your input field in AppSearchPageComponent needs the ngModel-directive in order to directly interact with the variable searchItem

```
<input class = "search" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchItem" (input)="changeComponent($event)">
```

And your AppSearchResultPageComponent needs it too, to get updated if searchItem changes.

```
<input class="input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchItem">
```

If you now enter a value into the input field in AppSearchPageComponent it directly appears in your input field in AppSearchResultPageComponent.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please mark is as solution to your problem.